# Why does unary operator & not require a complete type?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, incomplete-type, addressof

The following code compiles fine with both [gcc 7.2.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1zYIJnOnoiR7cB0b) and [clang 6.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JuMPpVyc0Qx6kplh).

```
#include <iostream>

struct stru;

void func(stru& s) {
  std::cout << &s << std::endl;
}

int main() {

}
```

I'm wondering how this is OK. What if `stru` has overloaded `operator&()`? The compiler should not be able to tell with simply a forward declaration like `struct stru`. In my opinion, only `std::addressof(s)` is OK with an incomplete type.

Comment: Implementation defined or undefined behaviour depending on C++ version see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: @RichardCritten *Unspecified* or undefined behaviour depending on C++ version. This is misrepresented on cppreference. If you scroll down to the "Defect reports" section on the same page, it's listed correctly there. And it has to be unspecified, not implementation-defined: for implementations performing whole-program analysis, it's unreasonable to expect them to document exactly when the complete type (including overloaded operator) is and isn't seen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What if `stru` has overloaded `operator&()`?

Then it is unspecified whether the overload will be called (See Oliv's comment for standard quote).

> How could unary operator & does not require a complete type?

That's how the standard has defined the language. The built-in address-of operator doesn't need to know the definition of the type, since that has no effect on where to get the address of the object.

One consideration for why it is a good thing: Compatibility with C.

Comment: [expr.unary]/5 *If & is applied to an lvalue of incomplete class type and the complete type declares operator&(), it is unspecified whether the operator has the built-in meaning or the operator function is called.[...]*

Comment: @Oliv thanks for the quote. I changed wording to be accurate.